# Сохранение и обновление программы

Tags: android, google-play

Я делаю сохранение в своем Android приложении с помощью SharedPreferences, после удаления приложения с телефона и повторной установки, сохраненные данные удалятся. В этом и вопрос, я собираюсь добавить приложение в маркет. Когда я буду дорабатывать приложение и обновлять его в маркете, я так понимаю, приложение будет удалять у пользователя и снова устанавливаться, то есть будет пропадать сохранение. Как сделать так , чтобы сохранение не пропадало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences сохраняются при обновлении программы и будут восстановлены в новой версии

Comment: При обновлении сохраняются не только `SharedPreferences`, но и все БД, файлы и проч.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень волновал этот вопрос.

Comment: :) а вспомнить случай, при обновлении игры или программ часто слетает весь прогресс, авторизация и тд?? и не волновался бы. Если не ошибаюсь, слетают SharedPreferences, если использовать имя файла с кастомным названием.

Comment: @Gorets, если название остается прежним, то даже такое не слетает.